# How to create New session ID after login (Jetty/Jboss server)

Tags: session, jboss, jetty

I have tried the session.invalidate() method in login page after authenticated user and it caused exception thus fail to get to default page. We use jetty (4.04) for server locally and jboss on qa/prod. Can someone tell me what needs to be done to avoid this?  I saw someone said set some flag in session-config but for jetty only Session-Timeout is allowed there. Also I don't see HttpServletRequest.changeSessionId method in request (javax.servlet version 2.4).

Thanks a lot.
Junping

Comment: I debugged into this issue (exception) and found that the net.sf.click.Context is not updating the new session though its servletRequest has the new session (servletRequest.getSession(true).  When the Context sets attribute, its session is invalide thus causing exception.  Our click's version is 1.0.  I tried version 1.4.2 and I looked at the Context and it has the same code as old version:

Comment: resolved myself.  Found that there was a setAttribute which is done by current context using the old session.  Before calling invalidate, saved that attribute.